# How do I programmatically override select2 css on form submit?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-select2

I'm trying to highlight select2 selects that are not filled when a user attempts to submit a form. I can't figure out how to override my pre-existing css styling from document load.

Here's my jquery attempt:

```
var $requiredUnfilledItems = $(".required:not(.filled)");
if ($requiredUnfilledItems.length > 0) {
  $requiredUnfilledItems.each( function(){
    $(this).addClass('warning-border');
  });
}
```

and my css for .warning-border:

```
.warning-border { 
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: red !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red !important;
}
```

which is trying to overwrite this:

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    border: thin solid lightgray;
    height: 30px;
}
```

But it doesn't work. I've also tried this (which might just demonstrate that I haven't mastered css yet) :

```
.warning-border, .select2-container.warning-border { 
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: red !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red !important;
}
```

Help?

Comment: Can you post a snippet or a fiddle so we can test on it?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to not use !important but understand how CSS cascades instead... there are better resources for this than me on the web--

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance

In my example snippet I made took the liberty of making a JQuery handler so the a text input field knows when it's filled and adds (or removes) a filled class to itself onkeyup-- you should add a handler for this somewhere unless one is already firing somewhere in your code (my guess is you already do).

I added those class combinations to the CSS so that they don't highlight in red (at the bottom of the stylesheet in the snipped).

You were using border-color, but the actual property you wanted to override was shorthanded in the CSS so I switched them so they are all shorthand and guaranteed to be affecting the same properties. I can't remember how it works off the top of my head, but this might have been an issue...

```js
$( "input[type=text]" ).keyup(function() {
  if(this.value != '') $(this).addClass('filled');
  else
    $(this).removeClass('filled')
});

$("form").submit(function(){
  var $requiredUnfilledItems = $('.required:not(.filled)'); 
  if ($requiredUnfilledItems.length > 0) 
  {$requiredUnfilledItems.each( function(){$(this).addClass('warning-border');
   });
  }
  else { alert("You entered in " + this.name.value); }
  return false;})
```

```css
.warning-border { 
    outline: none !important;
    border: thin solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}

.warning-border, .select2-container.warning-border { 
    outline: none !important;
    border: thin solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}

.warning-border.filled, .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    border: thin solid lightgray;
    height: 30px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" onsubmit="">
<input id="name" type="text" class="required filled" value="Name"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Tom, but this doesn't seem to fix my issue. All of my input elements were outlining fine with my previous code, as well as with this code. However, both my code and yours don't seem to do the same thing for select2 boxes

Comment: Can you post more of an example / snippet to the original question post-- like part of the form? Also try this-- put your CSS code for .warning-border below / after the .select2-* classes. Important will override on per-property basis, but having declarations after (closer to the document) will also override previously set values.